# An Inequality Involving Subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ of Positive Density

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Given a set $V$ of non-negative integers, let: $$V\left(t\right)\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\left\{ v\in V:0\leq v\leq t\right\} ,\textrm{ }\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$$ and let $\left|V\left(t\right)\right|$ denote the number of elements of $V\left(t\right)$. Recall that the (natural/asymptotic) density of $V$ is the quantity $d\left(V\right)$ defined by the limit (if it exists): $$d\left(V\right)\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left|V\left(t\right)\right|}{t}$$

My question is: if $V$ has positive density, does the inequality: $$\sup_{t\geq0}\left|d\left(V\right)t-\left|V\left(t\right)\right|\right|<\infty$$ necessarily hold? If not, then, for what kinds of $V$ does the inequality hold or fail?

Comment: Consider an infinite sequence of independent tosses of a fair coin, and let $V$ be the set of all $t$ such that the $t^{\text{th}}$ toss comes up heads. With probability one, the set $V$ has density $\frac12$, and your inequality fails. In other words, a random subset of $\mathbb N$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V = \{2^k | k \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then $d(V) = 0$, but $\sup\limits_{t \geqslant 0}|V(t)| = \infty$. If you want non-zero (and non-one) density - take, for example, set of all even numbers that are not powers of two.

It has nothing specific to do with density. Existence of $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \frac{f(t)}{t} = c$ means $f(t) = tc + o(t)$ while $|ct - V(t)|$ been bounded means $f(t) = tc + o(1)$, which is stronger.

Comment: Does the set of all even numbers which are not powers of two have a well-defined natural density?

Comment: It does, it's density is $\frac{1}{2}$. $|V(n)| = \lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil - \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$

Comment: Okay then, what's the best estimate for $\left|d\left(V\right)t-V\left(t\right)\right|$? I just need for $\frac{\left|d\left(V\right)t-V\left(t\right)\right|}{t^{1+\delta}}$ to be integrable with respect to $t$ on [1,∞) for all $\delta>0$. Is this possible?

Comment: It will be integrable for any $\delta > 1$, and there are sets for which it isn't integable for any $\delta \leqslant 1$ - for example, set of all prime numbers, or set $\{k \cdot \lceil \log k\rceil | k \in \mathbb N\}$.

Comment: The set of all primes doesn't count; it has zero density. I need to know if my integrability condition will hold for $\delta>0$ and a set $V$ with positive natural density.

Comment: Take set of all numbers that are prime or odd - it has density of $\frac{1}{2}$, but $V(t) \approx \frac{t}{2} + \frac{t}{\ln t}$, so your function is $\frac{1}{t^\delta \ln t}$.